# Loki js: 8 requests failed to load;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, storybook, lokijs

I have a frontend application using React. In the project I use Storybook. And for regression screenshot testing of ui-elements, I use the "loki" library (loki.js.org). "Loki" works fine locally("dev" mode), but I want to use it in CI.

And for this, following the documentation - https://loki.js.org/continuous-integration.html --- you need to build the storybook in the "build" mode and then run the "loki" in a special way:

```
loki --requireReference --reactUri file:. /storybook-static
```

in my case:

```
npx loki --requireReference --reactUri file: ./storybook-static
```

**But then after running "loki" I get an error:**

loki test v0.31.2
(node:5080) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.

Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

FAIL  chrome.app
Fetching stories
8 requests failed to load; file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/idris-project/storybook-static/sb-common-assets/nunito-sans-regular.woff2,
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/idris-project/storybook-static/sb-common-assets/nunito-sans-italic.woff2,
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/idris-project/storybook-static/sb-common-assets/nunito-sans-bold.woff2,
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/idris-project/storybook-static/sb-common-assets/nunito-sans-bold-italic.woff2,
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/idris-project/storybook-static/sb-preview/runtime.js,
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/idris-project/storybook-static/runtime~main.e5f69939.iframe.bundle.js,
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/idris-project/storybook-static/608.9033a121.iframe.bundle.js,
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/idris-project/storybook-static/main.d0385d06.iframe.bundle.js
Some visual tests failed to run

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgZa7.png)

```
Storybook version - "^7.0.12"
Loki version - "0.31.2"
```

Tried to run with "docker" but doesn't work either. I suppose that the versions of the storybook and loki conflict with each other.

Comment: Same problem. Please let me know if you fixed this and the way to solve